# How to read a specific part of a line in python?

Tags: python

I have a text file which contains:

```
abcde:12345
username:123123
```

I need to only read the part before the `':'` in a variable
and read the part after the `':'` in another variable.

I couldn't find any way to read a specific parts of the line

Answer (score 1):

You can use below python snippet that reads your text file and extracts the values before and after the ':' character, and stores them in separate variables:

```
with open('your_file.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        parts = line.strip().split(':')
        var1 = parts[0]
        var2 = parts[1]
        print(var1, var2)
```